# How to combine all values from a ThreadLocal<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I've run across .NET 4's `ThreadLocal<T>` and was wondering if there's a way to accumulate the `.Value` values from all threads.

In Microsoft's ppl C++ library they have [`Concurrency::combinable::combine_each`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470699.aspx), is there an equivalent method for .NET's `ThreadLocal`?

```
ThreadLocal<long> ticks = new ThreadLocal<long>();

void AddTicks(StopWatch sw)
{
    ticks.Value += sw.ElapsedTicks;
}

void ReportTimes()
{
    long totalTicks = /* How do I accumulate all the different values?  */;
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromTicks(totalTicks));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since .NET 4.5, Microsoft added an attribute called `Values` to the `ThreadLocal` class that does exactly what you need. Here's the way it works:

```
var localResult = new ThreadLocal<int>(() => 0, trackAllValues: true);
Parallel.For(0, 10000, i =>
{
    localResult.Value += Compute(i);
});

int result = localResult.Values.Sum();
```

The code above was obtained from the blog post: [New in .NET 4.5: ThreadLocal.Values](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-in-net-4-5-threadlocal-values/)

Answer (score 4):

This information is not available in .NET 4.0. For 4.5 and up, see Joao's answer.

Microsoft is [considering adding such a feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-feature-threadlocalt-values/). You will need to write a wrapper around `ThreadLocal<T>` to add this behavior.

[Here is a blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-8-reductionvariablet/) that gives some directions about how to write a wrapper.